# How to group and sort rows togther without hiding any rows?

Tags: mysql

I have a table `mytable`

```
id | name| location
---|-----|----------
1  | fff |  www
2  | bbb |  xxx
3  | aaa |  www
4  | eee |  xxx
5  | ddd |  yyy
6  | ccc |  xxx
```

How do I select it such that I get the names arranged in ascending order separated by their location ?

I am expecting output to be  :

```
 name| location
-----|----------
 aaa |  www
 fff |  www
 bbb |  xxx
 ccc |  xxx
 eee |  xxx
 ddd |  yyy
```

The sql :

```
SELECT name, location
FROM mytable
GROUP BY location
ORDER BY location, name ASC
```

gives :

```
 name| location
-----|----------
 bbb |  xxx
 ddd |  yyy
 fff |  www
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case you don't need to use GROUP BY , only:

```
   SELECT name, location
     FROM mytable
 ORDER BY location asc, name asc
```

It will give you your expected results